# Updating contentSize of a UIScrollView based UITableView height

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I'm having some trouble updating the size of my `UIScrollView` to adjust to my `UITableView` height changes.

my `UITableView` is not scrollable. Instead the size of my view changes based on the amount of cells in my `UITableView`.

I have one `UIViewController` That I use to load 3 different datasets. (which requires to update my UITableView to accommodate different amounts of data often)

So when I load the first dataset it works fine.

However, if I load a new one after that, with a different amount of cells. My contentSize of my UIScrollView is now wrong. (it keeps the size from whatever the previous dataset was).

Here's an example:

[image]

Where I went from a dataset that had more cells. To one with less. You can see I'm able to scroll down much further than I should be able to. (The end of the contentSize should be stopping 16 points after the white area.

After attempting to fix this issue for a while, I did manage to get something working. I get my data from an API, which sometimes take a long time to fetch. However, when It's done updating all the data in my tableView I was able to fix the contentsize to what I want with the following line of code:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
```

First action after that worked, was to put that earlier. (Before I attempt to update the data.) But unfortunately that doesn't seem to do anything at all.

So how can I as soon as I reload my UITableView with the data from CoreData (before attempting to fetch new data) set my contentSize correctly?

Here is the function that loads the data. (This happens instantly. It's the end of this function after the reload, I need to fix the contentsize.

```
func loadPortfolio() {

    println("----- Loading Portfolio Data -----")
    // Set the managedContext again.
    managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    // Check what API to get the data from
    if Formula == 1 {
        formulaEntity = "PortfolioBasic"
        println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
        formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/monthly_entry.json")
    } else if Formula == 2 {
        formulaEntity = "PortfolioPremium"
        formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/monthly_proff.json")
        println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
    } else if Formula == 3 {
        formulaEntity = "PortfolioBusiness"
        println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
        formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/monthly_fund.json")
    } else {
        println("Errror - Formula out of range.")
    }

    // Delete all the current objects in the dataset
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: formulaEntity)
    let a = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]
    stocks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for mo in a {
        stocks.append(mo)
    }

    // Saving the now empty context.
    managedContext.save(nil)


    // Setting the first cell to be white
    cellAlteration = 0

    // Reload the tableview with the new data.
    self.pHoldingsTable.reloadData()

    tableHeight.constant = CGFloat(stocks.count*50)


    // This doesn't work here for some reason?
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)

println("Finished loading portfolio")


    self.view.hideLoading()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
        self.updatePortfolio()
    }

}
```

I also tried putting the scrollView related line before the constraint update, but that didn't work either.

However. Below is my updatePortfolio() function which uses the exact same line of code, and works fine. Once this finishes running my contentView is being set to the correct size.

```
func updatePortfolio() {
    println("Updating Portfolio")
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == false {
        println("ERROR: - No Internet Connection")
    } else {
        // Delete all the current objects in the dataset
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: formulaEntity)
        let a = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]
        for mo in a {
            managedContext.deleteObject(mo)
        }
        // Removing them from the array
        stocks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        // Saving the now empty context.
        managedContext.save(nil)

        // Set up a fetch request for the API data
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName(formulaEntity, inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: formulaAPI!)
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        var formula = JSON(data: data!)

        // Loop through the api data.
        for (index: String, portfolio: JSON) in formula["portfolio"] {

            // Save the data into temporary variables
            stockName = portfolio["name"].stringValue.lowercaseString.capitalizedString
            ticker = portfolio["ticker"].stringValue
            purchasePrice = portfolio["purchase_price"].floatValue
            weight = portfolio["percentage_weight"].floatValue


            // Set up CoreData for inserting a new object.
            let stock = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

            // Save the temporary variables into coreData
            stock.setValue(stockName, forKey: "name")
            stock.setValue(ticker, forKey: "ticker")
            stock.setValue(action, forKey: "action")
            stock.setValue(purchasePrice, forKey: "purchasePrice")
            stock.setValue(weight, forKey: "weight")

            // Doing a bunch of API calls here. Irrelevant to the question and took up a ton of code, so skipped it to make it more readable.


            // This can simply be set, because it will be 0 if not found.
            stock.setValue(lastPrice, forKey: "lastPrice")

            // Error handling
            var error: NSError?
            if !managedContext.save(&error) {
                println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
            }
            // Append the object to the array. Which fills the UITableView
            stocks.append(stock)
        }

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            // Setting the first cell to be white
            cellAlteration = 0
            self.tableHeight.constant = CGFloat(self.stocks.count*50)
            self.pHoldingsTable.reloadData()
            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
            println("Finished Updating Portfolio")
        })
    }
}
```

I also tried putting the tableHeight constraint above the reload like It is in the update function. But it didn't make a difference.

Here's how my UIScrollView is set up:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.frame = view.bounds
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: contentView.frame.height)
}
```

This always gets the correct size the first time. But because this function is not called when the tableView changes. It does not update the contentSize automatically.

my contentView.frame.height changes depending the amount of cells in the UITableView. It's not a fixed height. (I never want my UITableView itself to scroll inside it's box)

Also in case my issues are constraint related and not in my function, I'm doing it all programatically. I'm not using storyboards or XIB files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused why you would use a tableView and a scrollView, since tableViews are a subclass of scrollViews, hence already scrollable.

Comment: I have other data in my view than just what's in the tableView. If you look at the screenshot, you can see a rounded border around the cells. Above my tableView I have other essential data, linecharts, pie charts, statistics etc. I need to be able to scroll up to those. or scroll to the bottom using a scrollView. Using only one, is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the grouped tableviews style.

To be sure: The only thing you want is not to have infinite cells below your last cell, right? If so, you should use the grouped table view style.

Using that style would save you a lot of work. If I understood your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I think there was a bit of a miscommunication, I don't have "infinite" cells below my tableView. It keeps the contentsize from whatever the viewController was before the new data.

If e.g. the last update had 9 cells. And the one I load now has 23. My screen stops at 9. (I can see a bit further using the bounce. But until my update function is finished I can't see the rest). Likewise, if I have 30 cells, I  update and only have 9. I can scroll much further than the 9 cells.

It's definitely not a problem with infinite cells. It's the contentsize (scrollable area)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with pinning constraints between views and subViews.

In scrollView, make sure the top and bottom of the tableView are pinned to the scrollview. Then if you want the scrollView to shorten with the tableView, make sure the scrollView is NOT pinned to the bottom of its parent view.

Comment: I do not have a constraint pinned to the bottom of anything regarding the UIScrollView. The only constraint I have for the scrollView itself is this: `H:|[contentView(contentWidth)]` Every other constraint is regarding the contentView and it's subviews. Now my contentView is however set with the following constraint.`"V:|-16-[pYieldsView]-16-[pDivView]-16-[pHoldingsView]-16-|"` Because I need the 16p padding at the bottom. But it should grow with the pHoldingsView (which changes height based on the UITableView) And it always gets the correct height the first time. Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: Let me edit my question with my constraint / scrollview setup. :)

Comment: I added my setup of the UIScrollView to the bottom of my question. :) hopefully that helps if it's there I'm going wrong.